# Python float with periodic decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to take into account the periodic decimals in my function, for example:

[image]

So instead of just having a function y * 0.44 or y * 0.55 the program would use as many decimals as possible: y * 0.44444444 or y * 0.55555555 in its calculations.

One way I think would be by looping through the decimals and adding .0 as many times as possible. However, is there a leaner way?

Comment: What would "adding .0" achieve?

Comment: 0.44 + 0.0044 = 0.4444 etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try defining the repeating values with fractional notation

```
point4=4/9   #0.4444444444...
point5=5/9    #0.5555555555...

y * point4
y * point5
```

To generalize to any repeating number, divide your number "n" with another number where every digit of "n" is replaced by 9

ex. 26/99 -> 0.26262626...

ex. 10203/99999 -> 0.102031020310203...

Answer (score 4):

This is a misunderstanding of how floats work. They have a limited size (usually 32 or 64 bits) and precision (they store a number using an exponent and a binary expansion).

So if you want to represent a number with infinite precision it is impossible with floats. You probably need to use a symbolic representation instead.

Even if you want to use the most decimal places possible, it is still a problem, because floats work in binary and not decimal, so there is no equal number of precise decimal places for every float. (for more information about floats see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic))

The best alternative I can think of, if you only need rational numbers, could be using the `fractions` module.

```py
In [1]: from fractions import Fraction

In [2]: Fraction(3, 4) * Fraction(5, 3)
Out[2]: Fraction(5, 4)
```

If you need more advanced stuff, you could try [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

One comment solved it:

0.44 --> 44/99 --> 0.44444444

0.58 --> 58/99 --> 0.58585858

0.4 --> 4/9 --> 0.44444

0.567 --> 567/999 --> 0.567567567

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Not quite. Scott's answer only shows single repeating digits, this one also shows multiple (and already did when you commented).

Comment: Scott's answer is right for 1 decimal (of course he could've written it for more decimals as well and then I would gladly accept his answer), however hopefully for now, this explains it easier and faster for others, seeking similar or same solutions.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's not immaterial. From Scott's answer It's not obvious how to do longer periods. And the OP called those two numbers an "example" and the question is clearly more general. This answer added useful additional information for that.

Comment: Sorry, I have to agree to disagree. Of course my question could be better phrased, however the point here is that someone with similar problem finds the solution as quickly as possible, while Scot's answer is right for any number of decimals, but it might not be understood as such, by someone who wants to find periodic float with repeating 4 decimals. If he gave examples for 1, 2, 3 decimals, then it is correctly interpreted right of the bat, which he did not. Yet. Therefore I am keeping my post.

Comment: My main point was that you could use a fractional representation to maximize precision. I've edited my answer with the more general solution